# Archive artifact in Nexus

Tags: versioning, nexus, artifact

Our internal Nexus repository has an artifact that we wish we never published, but unfortunately we did.  And various environments installed it.

I'd like to delete it from the repository so that nobody downloads the erroneous release again, but for the people who already downloaded & installed that artifact, it seems a bit deceptive to pretend the release never happened.  Is there a way to "archive" or "disable" an artifact so that it still is preserved somewhere for analysis or archeological purposes, but won't be installed by someone pulling artifacts for installation?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a feature in NXRM for disabling access to individual artifacts. This is a bit hacky but you could achieve it by

1. Creating a new hosted repository (either raw format or the same
   format that you are currently using)
2. Marking that repository as "offline" [image]
3. Moving the artifact to the archived repository.

Step 3 is the problematic part: If you are an NXRM PRO user on a recent version there are REST calls you can use for moving components. See here for more details https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/staging#Staging-RESTEndpoints

If you are an OSS user you will likely have to republish the same artifact to the archive repository and then delete it from the original repository.

(Note the above assumes you are using NXRM3 - if you are using NXRM2 take a look at https://blog.sonatype.com/2010/04/nexus-tip-moving-artifacts-between-nexus-repositories/)

Comment: Thanks - but I don't like that it leaves no record of the artifact in the original repository, so unless someone explicitly knew to go look in the archive repo, they still wouldn't know what happened.  Maybe I'll submit a feature request to Sonatype.

Comment: @KenWilliams feature requests can be filed here: https://issues.sonatype.org. It'd also be helpful if you shared a link to the ticket you create here so that anyone else who finds this post can vote on the ticket or add their 2 cents.